# Eagle: library with only common packages

Tags: eaglecad, footprint, library

is there some library with only common packages, but not compsed with devices?
I use components from many sources and either I would end with tons of librarioes, or with tons of differnet models (which I do not have) (usually with much  layers, which are not relevant, but somebody used them somwhere for something once) or I have to copy and re-create everything.

I would like just the pads/holes like 0802 and connect them with only parts I really have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library is called `ref-packages` in EAGLE's `lbr` directory, you can copy-paste packages to your custom devices in library editor.

But be warned that you **must** verify package you reuse with the real device's datasheet so that it would not appear that real device is hard, or even impossible to solder because its pins appeared to be longer/wider than defined in package you reused from the library.

Pads and holes themselves are basic elements within the library editor, I do not think there're special packages for only pad of special size.

Comment: I meant pads for 0805 resistor or something like. Maybe worded it bad, but the `ref-packages` is exactly what I was looking for. (BTW: I made "devices" for my mostly used pads or holes, like 1x1_BIG_PIN and 1x1_SLIM_PIN and 2x3_PAD and 3x2_BIG_PIN - used for ISCP connectors and contacts and such)